# Roxygen: Defaulting help to another function

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I'm writing the help for one function, and I would like a second function to display the same help file. How do I do this in Roxygen/devtools?

For example, consider the following:

**We first have a function with a full helpfile**

```
#' Plot random points
#' @param color Color of random points
#' @export
plotRandomPoints = function(color = "red"){
   plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(-2,2))
   drawRandomPoints(col = color)
}
```

**Now we have a second function we want to just share the same help file**

```
#' <link to plotRandomPoints>
#' @export
drawRandomPoints = function(color = "red"){
  points(rnorm(10), col = color)
}
```

How do we `<link to plotRandomPoints>`?

Comment: `@inherit source_function will inherit parameters, return, references, description, details, sections, and seealso from source_function().`https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the @rdname tag is what you're looking for. If you change the second code block to this

```
#' @rdname plotRandomPoints
#' @export
drawRandomPoints = function(color = "red"){
 points(rnorm(10), col = color)
}
```

the resulting help file should include both `plotRandomPoints()` and `drawRandomPoints()`